# Jquery маска номера телефона

Tags: java, html, jquery, jsp

День добрый! Подскажите пожалуйста. В интернете описана кучу методов использования масок на инпутах. Но не один из них у меня не заработал.

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>$Title$</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../WEB-INF/js/jquery.js"></script>
   <!-- Подключение jQuery плагина Masked Input -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../WEB-INF/js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" class="phone" id="phone">
  </body>
  </html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($){
    $("#phone").mask("99.99.9999");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Попробуйте эти: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ и https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/

Comment: Не вижу в вопросе ни Java, ни JSP.